# Hide a range of columns using script - Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have got a spreadsheet that is basically a diary of appointments containing 12 months, I have the below script contained within the spreadsheet that hides columns (to save time) the problem is that there is too much data and this takes a long time, especially the hideAll function!

I was wondering if there is a way I can change these functions to hide the columns as ranges instead of as individual columns, I haven't managed to find anything like this so far. I would need to be able to set up the menu the same and be able to hide each month individually and if possible hide all as a function also (like the existing script but in blocks not individually). This has to be ranges as I have columns in between each month that need to stay visible and not be hidden.

Please see example spreadsheet below (this is not an up to date version but the script it contains is what is used live on the real version!)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sOlQEzG1D29RaY86YeR1Da--c8t94J-ZAGjv52U4dsY/edit?usp=sharing

```
function onOpen(){
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Sophie\'s Menu :)')
  .addItem('Relative validation', 'copyValidation')
  .addItem('Relative rows, absolute columns', 'copyValidationColumnsAbsolute') 
  .addItem('Absolute rows, relative columns', 'copyValidationRowsAbsolute') 
  .addItem('Hide All Months', 'hideAll')
  .addItem('Hide January', 'hideCols1')
  .addItem('Hide February', 'hideCols2')
  .addItem('Hide March', 'hideCols3')
  .addItem('Hide April', 'hideCols4')
  .addItem('Hide May', 'hideCols5')
  .addItem('Hide June', 'hideCols6')
  .addItem('Hide July', 'hideCols7')
  .addItem('Hide August', 'hideCols8')
  .addItem('Hide September', 'hideCols9')
  .addItem('Hide October', 'hideCols10')
  .addItem('Hide November', 'hideCols11')
  .addItem('Hide December', 'hideCols12')
  .addToUi();
}

function copyValidation(rowsAbsolute, columnsAbsolute)
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var r = ss.getActiveRange();
  var dv = r.getDataValidations();
  var dvt = dv[0][0].getCriteriaType();
  if (dvt != SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.VALUE_IN_RANGE) return;
  var dvv = dv[0][0].getCriteriaValues();
  Logger.log(dvv);
  for (var i = 0; i < dv.length; i++)
  {
    for (var j = i ? 0 : 1; j < dv[0].length; j++)
    {

  dv[i][j] = dv[0][0].copy().withCriteria(dvt, [dvv[0].offset(rowsAbsolute ? 
  0 : i, columnsAbsolute ? 0 : j), dvv[1]]).build();
    }
  }
  r.setDataValidations(dv);
}

function copyValidationRowsAbsolute()
{
  copyValidation(true, false);
}

function copyValidationColumnsAbsolute()
{
  copyValidation(false, true);
}

function hideCols1(){

showhideCols('3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,
17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33',false);
}

function hideCols2(){
  showhideCols('35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,
  48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62',false);
}

function hideCols3(){

showhideCols('64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,
78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94',false);
}

function hideCols4(){
  showhideCols('96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,
  111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125',false);
}

//Right up to hideCols12 

function hideCols12(){
  showhideCols('348,349,350,351,352,353,354,355,356,357,358,359,360,361,362,363,
  364,365,366,367,368,369,370,371,372,373,374,375,376,377,378',false);
}

//I even have a hideAll function that contains every single column listed above! 

function showhideCols(colscsv,show){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  if(!colscsv){
    var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Enter Column Numbers separated by 
commas.', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().Button.OK);
    var cA=resp.getResponseText().split(',');
  }else{
    var cA=colscsv.split(',');
  }
  for(var i=0;i<cA.length;i++){
    if(show){
      sh.showColumns(cA[i]);
    }else{
      sh.hideColumns(cA[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the indexes in the `hideColsN()` are static, then you only need to send the starting `columnIndex` and the `numColumns` in the range to [hideColumns(columnIndex, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hideColumns(Integer,Integer))

```
function hideCols1(){
  showhideCols(3, 31, false);
}
```

```
function showhideCols(start, amount, show){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();

  // set variables to the list of numbers from the prompt
  // may want to change it to take the startIndex and number of columns to hide/show. 
  // also there was not a way listed to determine if the columns should be hidden or not.
  if(!start){
    var resp=SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt('Enter Column Numbers separated by commas.', SpreadsheetApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK);
    var cA=resp.getResponseText().split(',');
    var start = cA[0];
    var amount = cA.length;
    var show = false;
  }
  // Show or hide column ranges in one call
  if(show){
    sh.showColumns(start, amount);
  }else{
    sh.hideColumns(start, amount);
  }

}
```

**edit:** I may be overlooking it, but I didnt see your `hideAll()` method so that was not added to this answer

Comment: Hi random-parts, thank you for the answer, it works amazingly. Regarding the hide all function, this is the item when added to the list: '.addItem('Hide All Months', 'hideAll')' and this is the function itself: function 'hideAll(){
  showhideCols('3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 //right up to the last column }' This works but is extremely slow, for this to work I would need to be able to add multiple ranges of columns (because of the breakers between each month) to one function. So it will hide 12 ranges of columns in one. If this is not possible then that is fine as your answer is great already. Thank you.

Comment: you could probably get away with making the `hideAll()` call each of the 12 `hideColN()`. Its a bit of an ugly hack, but with only 12 hits it should still complete way before the script time-out limit.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will give that a go! All of my script is pretty rough anyway so no change there hah!